# How to pass value from apple script to shell script in Automator?

Tags: macos, shell, applescript, automator

I'm planning to run a shell script followed by a AppleScript. But I would like to know if it is possible to pass a parameter value to shell script as follows.

[image]

I'm getting some weird error which I do not understand. Can someone please help me understand the error and provide a way to pass value (Continue/Don't Continue) to Shell script from Apple Script?

Code in Text format:

```
on run {input, parameters}

   set theDialogText to "By running this script, it will update your hosts file. Would you like to continue?"

   set isupdate to display dialog theDialogText buttons {"Don't Continue", "Continue"} default button "Continue" cancel button "Don't Continue"

return {isupdate}
```

end run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all please post text, not an image.

The error occurs because `display dialog` returns a record (in terms of Objective-C a dictionary) but the parameter must be a string.

You have to write

```
set isUpdate to button returned of (display dialog ... )
```